# Detect locale of a date which is in string format using Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date

I have a date in string format and like 12/11/2017 and I want to detect the what locale the date belongs to. For example, in US date is written as mm/dd/yyyy. So for the above date, my program should output US locale. Based on input there should be different locale.

I am not able to find the solution for this problem on any of the other discussions. I want to detect the locale of a date i.e. in what regions format is the date written. I have taken US as an example. The date could be of any locale format like UK, France, Germany, etc.

Comment: How can you tell it's a US locale?   That could be Dec 11, or the 12th of Nov

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Well I don't know but for my case, Colombia, that's 12th Nov. are you sure that your service is only going to be use on the US?

Comment: Java has a locale library which has format for all dates. I have to check to what locale does my string match.
For US, this is the format:
{The Date for United States:
 FULL = Tuesday, January 2, 2018
 LONG = January 2, 2018
 MEDIUM = Jan 2, 2018
 SHORT = 1/2/18}

if my string date is like "1/2/18", I should be able to print the locale that is US.

I should be able to detect locales like US, UK, Germany, France.

Comment: @DavidZimmerman That is my question. It could be different locale too but I am trying to keep the detection to a few countries only. It is not really possible as the it could be dd/mm or mm/dd if it is below number 12 for both month and day.

Comment: @Blasanka I tried some stuff. I can print the dates in different locale but I am not able to find a method to detect the locale automatically. I dont want to go in putting a lot of if conditions for every locale as that method will be time consuming .

Comment: In general you cannot. A number of locales will fit your string, so you can tell that it is one of those, but not which one.

Comment: You may iterate over the possible locales (either `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` or your own list of locales you want to be able to detect), for each use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()` with all possible styles (full, long, medium, short) and strict resolver style and try parsing your string into a date. If it succeeds, you have got a possible locale, but in most cases just one of several possible.

Comment: As an aside and since you tagged your question with simpledateformat, please don’t use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class for this. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you iterate over the possible locales (either Locale.getAvailableLocales() or your own list of locales you want to be able to detect), for each use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()` with all possible styles (full, long, medium, short, or just those that you consider relevant) and try parsing your string into a date. If it succeeds, you have got a possible locale, but just one of several possible. The following method returns an array of all possible locales for a given date string.

```
public static Locale[] possibleLocalesForDateString(String dateString) {
    Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    return Arrays.stream(availableLocales)
            .filter(loc -> {
                for (FormatStyle style : FormatStyle.values()) {
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
                            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(style).withLocale(loc);
                    try {
                        LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
                        // succeeded; this is a possible locale
                        return true;
                    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
                        // failed; ignore this locale/format style combination
                    }
                }
                return false;
            })
            .toArray(Locale[]::new);
}
```

On my Java 8 `possibleLocalesForDateString("12/11/2017")` returns an array of 50 locales. Starting out from 160 available locales the method has reduced to a little less than a third of the possibilities. The array does *not* include US locale because the short US format uses two-digit year, while the medium format is like `Dec 11, 2017`.

Other results:

- `12/11/17` gives as many as 67 possible locales including US (en_US) and France (fr_FR). The date is understood as Dec 11 in the US and as 12 Nov in France.
- `30/11/17` gives “just” 60 locales. US is no longer included, France still is. Using a day-of-month greater than 12 helps narrow down the possibilities.
- Conversely `12/31/17` gives just the remaining 7 locales including US; but it’s still ambiguous.
- Trying a German date string: `11.12.17`. I got 30 locales back including Germany (de_DE).

**Avoid `SimpleDateFormat`**. Since you tagged your question with simpledateformat, I wanted to mention that the `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with. So I am using classes and enums from that API in my method.

**Link**: [Oracle Tutorial on Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), where the use of `java.time` is explained. You can find many other resources out there.

Comment: Thanks....big help. I did it in a different way and now instead of detecting the locale, I am directly converting it into the standard format. Also giving user the option to specify the date format they have in the dataset like YMD, DMY or MDY.

Answer (score 0):

No. Localized date-time formats are ambiguous. Your example of `12/11/2017` could be either December 11 or November 12. See a [list of date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

Separate the concerns of *content* and *presentation*.

- **Content**

  - *java.time*
    Within your Java app, date-time values should be represented by java.time objects (avoid the legacy date-time classes).
  - *ISO 8601*
    When serializing date-time values to text for storage or exchange, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats: `2017-12-11`. Fortunately, the java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.
- **Presentation**

  - *Localize*
    Use a `Locale` to generate a localized string only for presentation to the user, never for internal use as data. See the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).